# send class name as parameter in swift

Tags: swift, object, protocols

How can I send a class name as a parameter in swift? Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. I have an object that I want it to take 2 different objects (object A, object B) as part of its initializers.
2. Also, I need to be sure that both objects contain an UIImageView each one of them.

Example:

```
class A {
    var view: UIImageView!
    //rest of the code for object A
}

class B {
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    //rest of the code for object B
}

class C {
    init(someClass1: AnyClass, someClass2: AnyClass) {
        //make sure someClass1.imageView
        //make sure someClass2.imageView
    }
    //rest of the code for object C
}
```

So, basically I need to send those class names/types to initialize class C, and that A and B conform and have an UIImageView. I guess it should be something like protocols but not sure how to implement it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two ways to do it: protocols or inheritance**. Protocols are usually the way to go because they are more flexible. There is a huge tradition of protocols in Objective C because that language doesn't support multiple inheritance, but Swift does! The reasons to choose protocols or inheritance are not language-based in Swift but purely architectural-based, which is great. So depending on the structure of your app you should chose the best approach.

Using a protocol:

```
// Any class conforming to the protocol P must
// have a property called view because it is not optional
protocol P {
    var view: NSImageView? { get set }
}

class A: P {
    var view: NSImageView?
    // ...
}

class B: P {
    var view: NSImageView?
    // ...
}

class C {
    init(someClass1: P, someClass2: P) {
        if someClass1.view != nil && someClass2.view != nil {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Using inheritance:

```
// Parent class. Any subclass already includes all the 
// properties and methods, so you don't have to redeclare them.
class P {
    var view: NSImageView?
}

class A: P {
}

class B: P {
}

class C {
    init(someClass1: P, someClass2: P) {
        if someClass1.view != nil && someClass2.view != nil {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! after some research based on your answer, I would just add... if protocol conformance is needed (A as? P, A is P) then protocol P should be an objc protocol (@objc protocol P ...)